# ¿Cómo puedo pasar eso a python? Es para capturar un texto de la consola de comandos

Tags: java, python-3.x

necesito ayuda con transformar un código de *java* a *python*, que es para leer y traer un dato desde la consola, en este caso puerto y sesión.

Adjunto el código :

```
BufferedReader lectura = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String texto;
        while ((texto = lectura.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(texto);

            if (texto.startsWith("Puerto:")) {
                String[] temp;
                temp = texto.split(": ");
                puerto = temp[1];
            } else if (texto.startsWith("Sesion:")) {
                String[] temp;
                temp = texto.split(": ");
                sesion = temp[1];
            }

        }
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so], te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour], así entenderás como funciona el sitio y recibirás tu primera medalla. Si puedes agregar a tu pregunta el código en `python` de lo que hayas intentado, mostrando las dificultades encontradas y el resultado esperado, seguramente obtendrás una respuesta. Puedes hacer clic en [edit] y agregar lo que te he indicado. Saludos

Comment: No creo que haya composición de objetos de lectoescritura como en Java, pero podrías usar [tag:jython] para reusar tu código Java

Comment: La traducción a python es prácticamente directa, salvo detalles de sintaxis,  pues python tiene también los métodos de cadena `startswith()` y `split()`. Para lectura de la entrada estándar usarías `texto = input()`, y para mostrarlo en la salida estándar `print(texto)` ¿Cuál es la dificultad concreta que has encontrado?

Answer (score 0):

Sinceramente, no sé qué es lo que quieres hacer ni que es puerto ni sesión, pero he traducido tu código a Python. Sin más contexto no puedo probarlo para saber como funciona.

```py
texto= input()
while (not texto == ""):
    print (texto)
    if (texto.startswith("Puerto:")):
        temp= texto.split(": ")
        puerto= temp[1]
    elif (texto.startswith("Sesion:")):
        temp= texto.split(": ")
        sesion= temp[1]
```

Espero haberte ayudado, y si hay algún fallo, que alguien me lo diga e intentaré correguirlo, pero básicamente sería eso.